# How to setup CloudWatch embedded metrics format (emf) in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I'm trying to use CloudWatch embedded metrics format (emf) inside a beanstalk environment running Docker image.

(Documentation on emf [here](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/amazon-cloudwatch-launches-embedded-metric-format/) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Embedded_Metric_Format_Generation_CloudWatch_Agent.html) )

To be able to emit emf metrics, the aws-cloudwatch-agent needs to have the following configuration:

```
{
  "logs": {
    "metrics_collected": {
      "emf": { }
    }
  }
}
```

However I'm not able to find the namespace definition to pass emf configuration to beanstalk, using the `.ebextensions` method described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html).
The available namespaces seem to just stream the existing logs.

How can I enable CloudWatch emf publishing in an elastic beanstalk environment?

Comment: Not sure if this what you are looking for. But here you go - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62123153/logging-custom-metrics-using-aws-cloudwatch-agent-and-python

Comment: @GowthamBhat - Thanks, it was not exactly the answer but pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass additional configuration use platform hooks described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63457272/log-streaming-and-premissions-with-ebextensions). More detail on platform hooks: [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html),

1. I've included `.platform/hooks/predeploy/emf-config.sh` with content:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo '{
        "logs": {
          "metrics_collected": {
            "emf": { }
          }
        }
      }' > "/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/emf_metrics.json"
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/bin/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-ctl -a append-config
```

2. If you use docker, make sure to include this files in your docker image. Using CDK pipeline I've included:

```
    (...)
    artifacts: {
        files: [
            "Dockerrun.aws.json",
            ".platform/hooks/**/*"
        ]
    },
```

1. Finally, make sure to add execution permissions to the .sh file. [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63399252/how-do-you-add-chmod-x-permission-to-an-aws-elastic-beanstalk-platform-hook)

```
chmod +x path/to/emf-config.sh
git update-index --chmod=+x path/to/emf-config.sh
```